# How to let php or mysql remember last page's information?

Tags: php, html

So I have this query to make pagination with limit offset

```
$sql = 'select count(*) as rank'
     . 'from table'
     . 'limit ' . ($p-1) * 20 . ',' . 20
     . 'order by rank desc';
```

$p represents present page. So it reads 0,20 for first page, 20,20 for next page and so on.

Then php side, I do some logic to get ranking

```php
<?php
$prev = 0;
for ($i, $i<=20, $i++){
    $c = current($query_result);
    $ranking = (int)$c['rank']
    if ($rank !== $prev){
        $ranking = $i;
    }
    // ...
    next($query_result);
}
```

this pseudo code works okay with whole version, but the problem is when $p became 2, the rank is reset and it start from 1st...

```
As is: 
the first post's ranking = 1st in 2nd page
To be: 
the first post's ranking = 21st in 2nd page(if first page's last rank was 20th.)
```

how do I do this?!

Comment: to make pagination you have to include it in the link for the next and previous page, by using query string params in the href attribute.

Comment: like [pagination](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)